# Static method cannot access instance members of a class

Tags: java, class, static-methods

In Liang's 9th edition *Introduction to Java Programming* it states, "A static method cannot access instance members of a class," (pg 312).  I see why an instance member of a class would need to access a method (which might be static), but why would a method need to access an instance member?  To me, "access" means "access by way of the dot operator."  In other words:

```
 Class myClass = new Class();
 myClass.someStaticMethod();
```

makes sense, whereas:

```
 someNonStaticMethod.myClass
```

or

```
 someStaticMethod.myClass
```

does not.  Is the someNonStaticMethod.myClass syntax allowed?  I don't believe I've ever seen such formatting.  If it is not allowed, why mention that static methods cannot access instance members of a class?

Please help lift my confusion.

-DI

Comment: It's talking about the code *within* the static method, e.g. `public static void someStaticMethod() { someInstanceMethod(); }` is invalid.

Comment: @Digital: By the way, the preferred way to access a static method is, using your example, `Class.someStaticMethod()`, not via an instance of the class (i.e. your `myClass.someStaticMethod();`)

Comment: @Griffey Dog   Is myClass.someStaticMethod() even possible?

Comment: Yes, it is _possible_ to call the static method that way, but it's really just a "feature" of Java syntax that allows it to be so. Doing it that way can be confusing, however, in that it looks like an _instance_ method call even though it is not, and for that reason should be avoided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing an instance member means accessing a *field or attribute* of the instance, not the instance itself since that would not compile. A dot does not literally mean "accessing" in the exact way you think and I guess that's the source of confusion you have. The dot is used to call a method on a certain object (see this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html)) or to access a field of an object (or class if the field is static).

For example, assuming the class is defined as follows:

```
class MyClass {

   private int x;

   static void foo() {
      ... // foo cannot access member x
   }
}
```

So in method `foo`, you can't reference `x` because it is a member field of `MyClass` that is bound to an *instance* of `MyClass`.

Also see [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to understand the difference between static members and instance members.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access instance variables from static methods.

```
public class Example {
    private Object instanceVariable;
    public static void staticMethod() {
        // Cannot use this in a static context
        this.instanceVariable = null;
    }
}
```

You can access instance variables from instance methods.

```
public class Example {
    private Object instanceVariable;
    public void instanceMethod() {
        this.instanceVariable = null;
    }
}
```

You should not access static variables from instance methods using `this`.

```
public class Example {
    private static Object staticVariable;
    public void instanceMethod() {
        // The static field Example.staticVariable should be accessed in a static way
        this.staticVariable = null;
    }
}
```

You can always access static variables. You should use the class name.

```
public class Example {
    private static Object staticVariable;
    public void instanceMethod() {
        Example.staticVariable = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A static method cannot refer to a non-Static instance field of a class.

If you want to understand why: A static method can be called without having an instance of a class, thus a non-static would not exist anyway when the method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It is talking about this:

```
public MyClass
{
   private String test;

   public static String getTest()
   {
       return this.test; //this is not possible because a static method cannot access an instance variable or method
   }

}
```

The reason a static method can't access instance variable is because static references the class not a specific instance of the class so there is no instance variable to access.  Test will only exist when `new MyClass` is used now test will exist. But if I call static method `MyClass.getTest()` there is not `test` instance variable created.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to access instance variables in static methods by creating objects

```
public class Test {
int x =10;

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Test t1 = new Test();
    System.out.println(t1.x);
}
```

}

Comment: That was not the question. The questioner was confused about methods accessing class instances.